# Marshaling structure with strings on WinRT

Tags: c#, encoding, arm, marshalling, msdn

I am developing a stripped down Windows IoT Core ARM port of a desktop application as a proof of concept for more distribution options with single-board computers (using a Raspberry Pi3 B+ at the moment). We need to marshal an unmanaged C array of null-terminated string pairs, like so:

```
// The C struct
typedef struct {
const char *key;
char* value;
} Pair;

// Its managed counterpart
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Pair
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string Key;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string Value;
}
```

The following PInvoke currently working on our WPF and Forms applications leaves a pointer to the data in info and the amount of elements in infoLength:

```
[DllImport("path/to.dll", EntryPoint = "unmanagedfunction", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern OperationResultEnum GetDeviceInfo(IntPtr session, out IntPtr info, out int infoLength);
```

Which we then marshal using the following generic function:

```
public static T[] GetArray(IntPtr ptr, int length)
    {
        T[] array = new T[length];
        Type type = typeof(T);
        IntPtr offsetPtr = ptr;
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(type);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(offsetPtr, type);
            offsetPtr = new IntPtr(offsetPtr.ToInt64() + size);
        }

        return array;
    }
```

This appears to work in our UWP IoT Core app, but for some outputs it fails somewhere in the middle of the array with a System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: "No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page". We have narrowed it down to an issue of encoding: the offending Pair.Key is a name containing a diacritic (í). The default encoding of the Pi appears to be UTF-8, while the default encoding of the device the C library interacts with is ANSI.

How can we fix this? The C half is more or less immutable as it is already in wide use. We have tried several marshaling options without success. I tried writing a custom marshaler, which throws at runtime because apparently custom marshalers are not supported in WinRT. Another theoretical option would be implementing a DecoderFallback, but I don't see any way of getting Marshal.PtrToStructure to use any encoding different from Encoding.Default, which is read-only.

Comment: There is [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn823314(v=vs.110).aspx) method. `Encoding.GetString(byte*, int)`. You could use that to marshal "manually" the strings (so instead of using `Marshal.PtrToStructure` you manually create the `Pair`, then do two `encoding.GetString()`...

Comment: This was among the things I tried, but it is yielding mojibake. On an unsafe context, I initialize `byte* walker = (byte*)offsetPtr`, increment it until a \0 is reached, then call `Encoding.GetEncoding(0).GetString((byte*)offsetPtr, (int)(walker - (byte*)offsetPtr))`