# .NET Core and Marshaling on Linux

Tags: c#, .net-core, marshalling, dllimport, c-libraries

I got third-party native C `library.so` in my .NET Core 3.1 application under linux os (debian).

There was identical `library.dll` under Windows with .NET SDK for it.
The Windows and linux C-libraries have the same methods signatures, I had check them.

With the help of dotpeek I adopt the code of sdk to linux app:

```
[DllImport("library.so", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
internal static extern uint FindEntites(out FoundResultsStruct foundResult);
...
internal ArrayList FillCollection()
{
    var innerList = new ArrayList();

    FoundResultsStruct results;
    var code = FindEntites(out results);

    IntPtr ptr = results.Value;

    if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
        throw new Exception();

    int num = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(FoundEntityStruct));

    for (long index = 0; index < results.Count; ++index)
    {
        innerList.Add(new CollectionEntity(Marshal.PtrToStructure<FoundEntityStruct>(ptr))); //point of Exception
        ptr = (IntPtr)((long)ptr + (long)num);
    }

    return innerList;
}
```

When I run the code, it throws the exception at `point of Exception` at the `index` variable equals 0, the first element of collection:

> No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page. (0x80070459)
>
> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page. (0x80070459)
>
> at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructureHelper(IntPtr ptr, Object structure, Boolean allowValueClasses)
> at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructureHelper(IntPtr ptr, Type structureType)
> at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(IntPtr ptr, Type structureType)
> at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure[T](IntPtr ptr)
> at MyApp.EntitesCollection.FillCollection() in C:\Projects\MyApp\EntitesCollection.cs:line 77

I suppose it cause native C-library interacts with ANSI encoding instead of UTF-8.

I had try to change the `CharSet` of `DllImport` attribute to `CharSet.Ansi/Unicode/Auto` - it has no effect.

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51021214/marshaling-structure-with-strings-on-winrt), looks like it's similar case, but didn't understand the solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: `(IntPtr)((long)ptr + (long)num)` looks a little bit strange to me and can be replaced by something like `IntPtr.Add(ptr, num);`. I don't think that it can cause the problem though.

Comment: I am not skilled enougth at marshaling e.t.c. 
It is original code from windows sdk. But this is guaranteed not to be the reason for the exception.

Comment: Please show the definition of `FoundResultsStruct` in both native and C#.

Comment: @Charlieface I can show c# struct tomorrow, but how can I show you native struct? I have no native sources (

Comment: Do you not have any documentation or headers? How did you create the C# side if you didn't know the native side?

Comment: @Charlieface my code is a copy via dotpeek from windows sdk-library (net framework 4.3) adopted to netcore. But i'll to find docs for c-library.

Comment: OK if it's a public DLL why don't you just tell us exactly which function and struct rather than leavng us guessing in the dark?

Comment: @Charlieface C-Library isn't public.